# how to access the last key or element of a dynamic object or json in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this structure

```
{
"step1":{...}
}
```

```
{
"step1":{...},
"step2":{...},
}
```

```
{
"step1":{...},
"step2":{...},
"step2":{...},
}
```

the object changes the number of elements according to the process transaction, regardless of the size I always need the last element

Answer (score 0):

Technically JSON is not ordered structure, so we can not say last element without decide the order.

We can convert json to table, sort it's rows by some parameter and pick one row:

```
select * 
from json_each('{"step1":"a","step2":"b","step3":"c"}'::json)
order by key desc limit 1
```

[run SQL online](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/cd465d154d5dc3fdd1da3decd7767f27/)